# Button on click get div element with it´s child elements addressed. The function should be required inside the div and not be toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the html div box which should be manipulated. The class "feedback-box-no" should be shown when clicked button "no".

```
 <div class="button-position">
          <input type="button" class="button-style-1" value="JA?" id="buttonYes">
          <input type="button" class="button-style-2" value="NEIN?" id="buttonNo">
          <div class="feedback-box-no">
            <p class="feedback-text">
             This is the text of the feedback div!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The div style is hidden by default:

```
.feedback-box-no {
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 140px;
    left: 29px;
    top: 104px;
    background-color: #597359;
    border-radius: 15px;
    visibility: hidden;

    /* -webkit-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    -moz-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    -ms-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    -o-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1; */
}

/* @keyframes feedback-no {
    from {
        top: 1500px;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    to {
        top: 104px;
        visibility: visible;
    }
} */
```

The JS:

The event target manipulation only worked by changing the button style element. But I want the new div to be shown. Till here I got any console error: Which says: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') at HTMLInputElement.

```
const clickedNo = document.querySelector('#buttonNo');

clickedNo.addEventListener('click', (event, eventChange) => {

    const event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent(eventChange, true, false); 
    const getFeedback = event.querySelector('feedback-box-no');
    getFeedback = event.currentTarget;
    getFeedback.style.visibility = "visible";

});
```

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to toggle visibility of the element with .feedback-box-no class ?

Comment: I don´t want to toggle! It should be a single click event. When clicking on the buttons No - it should show the div box of div class="feedback-box-no">
            <p class="feedback-text">
             This is the text of the feedback div!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do it

```js
const toggleVisibilityByClass = (elementClass) => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`.${elementClass}`);
  elements.forEach(el => {
    el.style.visibility = 'visible';
  });
}
```

```css
.feedback-box-no {
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 140px;
    left: 29px;
    top: 104px;
    background-color: #597359;
    border-radius: 15px;
    visibility: hidden;

    /* -webkit-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    -moz-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    -ms-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    -o-animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    animation: feedback-no 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1; */
}

/* @keyframes feedback-no {
    from {
        top: 1500px;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    to {
        top: 104px;
        visibility: visible;
    }
} */
```

```html
<div class="button-position">
    <input type="button" class="button-style-1" value="JA?" id="buttonYes" >
    <input type="button" class="button-style-2" value="NEIN?" id="buttonNo" onclick="toggleVisibilityByClass(`feedback-box-no`)">
    <div class="feedback-box-no">
        <p class="feedback-text">
            This is the text of the feedback div!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although in your code there is no assignment to the button as event listener!

Comment: you dont need to assign it within the script,i ve set the onclick listener directly to html, also you need the loop because we get a collection of elements by class,which can be multiple elements,if you want just to manipulate a single element you should just give it an id,which is unique

Comment: Why toggle?  There should no toggle be required.  I think a loop is although not necessary. Its just a single button event.

Comment: sure,i can rename it,its not toggling it anyway,i had it named it that way initially and i didn't change it

Comment: I would like to do that, I have still to less miss reputations!

Answer (score 0):

```
const clickedNo = document.querySelector('#buttonNo');

clickedNo.addEventListener('click', (eventChange) => {

    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.feedback-box-no');
    elements.forEach(el => {
        el.style.visibility = 'visible';
    });

});
```